# C# Serial Wedge

Tags: c#, keyboard, serial-port

C#, WinForms, .Net 2.0

I'd like to create my own software serial wedge in C#.  I have all the code for the serial I/O, and can get the data converted from Hex to ASCII and into a database or listbox.  But am unsure how to translate the data into key presses that will go into the active application.

Can someone direct me to an article or point me in the right direction?

Comment: you want to simulate a key press using C#?

Comment: I think you mean something like a 'shim': you want an application which reads from data the serial port, and converts that data to keystrokes which it pushes into another application: so that the effect is like using the serial port to send keystrokes to an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx) has instructions about how to use SendKeys to do just what you want.